# How to find the last saved file

Tags: macos, file

I don't know when I stopped working yesterday, but very likely I saved a file before shutting down my computer.

How can I find the (not system owned) file with the last save timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show a finder window sorted by date modified.

- Open a File Menu > New Finder window, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>
- If 'All my Files' isn't the default, View menu > All my Files or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>
- Sort as List  [image], View menu, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>
- By default this doesn't show, so Right Click the header bar & check Date Modified 
  [image]
- Sort by Date Modified, with newest to the top by clicking that column in the header bar  - [image]

Your most recently saved file will now be at the top of the list.

Comment: Now this is fantastic! I didn't even know about "All my Files". How handy! I thought I would have to go through the Terminal and do some complicated `find`. Oh God, how I love Apple again ♥ – And, wow, thanks for the wonderfully comprehensive answer. Wish I could give you more than the standard rep.

Comment: Welcome. The All My Files category is relatively new, maybe since Yosemite [I'm not certain] & is the default view for new users, but not for us old timers who have been updating 'in place' for years :)